# Bug report for extended reports- Post on Github...?

Tags: reports, bug-reporting

Can I post this here? Or do I need to go on https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport ? I am a user with no development expertise or ability to fix anything, would just love it if this report could work :)

The extended report 
Extended Report - Editable Activities - Template
has many bugs.
1. It does not save sort settings for more than one column
-Example: If you add a second sort column, then save, then look at the sort columns, it won't have saved the additional sort column.

2.It won't change sort settings
-Example: It won't update 'section header/group by' settings. If you check a section header, save, then uncheck and refresh results, it still keeps the section header

3. Checking 'section header/group by' in the header doesn't group by.It creates a header for each activity rather than grouping those with a shared field value under the header.
   -Example: If you sort by Activity status and check the 'section header/group by', it will have a "scheduled" header for each activity that is scheduled, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome to post an Issue on the extension. Whether Eileen or Fuzion will get to it without some bribery is another question.

Comment: OK, I filed it on that link thanks